# Field doesn't exist in destination table Access 2016

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import a csv file into my Access database with an Excel macro with the following command:

```
AppAcc.DoCmd.TransferText cImportDelim, "", "US_Before", "R:\ProBusiness\Before_Data.csv", True
```

When it hits this line, I get a run time error 2391 Field "PK__ doesn't exist in the destination table US_Before.

I have checked all of the headings in the Access table as well as the csv file and they all appear to match to me.  None of the headings have spaces in the name.  I have also compile access, compacted and repaired the database, rebooted my machine, and made sure there are no extra columns or rows in the data file. We are on Office 365 and Windows 10.

This same line works for a Canadian file (different field names) without any issues.

I'm not sure what the issue is.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks for your time.......

Comment: "and they all appear to match to me" -- sometimes spotting a typo can be brain-meltingly hard. Why not include the table definition so we can definitively rule out a typo? As it stands, there's not much to chew on.

Comment: What's the header of the CSV file looking like?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...I've got a Word document with all of the field names and data  type, will that help?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...is there some way for me to attach this file to my question?  thanks for your help.....

Comment: Please don't, and no there isn't. You want the content to be readable *here*, in the post itself (not a screenshot, not a 3rd-party download link).

Comment: Do you use only 0-9, a-z in the field names? Does field PK__ exist in the target database?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...there are several field names ("Address2", EMP_CHR12, EMP_DATE1) that have numbers.  The only special character is '_' in the field names.  Field PK__ doesn't exist in either the tables or data source

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...I'm not using a import specification.  Would that help?

Comment: You mean there's an apostrophe in a field name?

Comment: @peakpeak...the only special character is an underscore

Comment: @MathieuGuindon...one of the field names is ID.  Would that cause an issue?

Comment: Depends what the table structure is and whether autonumber inserts are allowed. First thing I'd try would be to run the CA and US files through a diff tool in Notepad++ and see if the headers are different.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon....The 2 files are different....different field names, different number of columns...

Comment: Ok, so next thing I'd try is to import the US file into a new table, then diff the data definition for the new and existing US tables. Access lets you script `create table`, right? (not familiar with Access)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon......turns out the issue was the file type that was causing the issue.  I was working with xlsx files and they needed to be csv files.  Once I made that change, they imported without any issues like I expected them to.  thanks for your help....